# Applying SetNull to multiple values at same time (array) gives Syntax error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

This is not working

[image: SetNull several values at a time]

I've got this error:
[image: Error!]

I've tried several combinations:

```
SetNull("rocksoilver12"==10 OR "rocksoilver12"==14, "rocksoilver12")

SetNull("rocksoilver12"==10 or "rocksoilver12"==14, "rocksoilver12")

SetNull("rocksoilver12"==10 OR "rocksoilver12"==14, "rocksoilver12")

SetNull("rocksoilver12" IN (10,14), "rocksoilver12")

SetNull("rocksoilver12" IN [10,14], "rocksoilver12")

SetNull("rocksoilver12" in [10,14], "rocksoilver12")
```

This is the error message that I've got:
[image]

None of them worked :/

Now, this works fine:

```
SetNull("rocksoilver12"==10, "rocksoilver12")
```

How can I use SetNull to delete multiple cell values at a time?

Comment: Have you tried a lower case 'in', that should be valid python syntax. I'm pretty sure operators are case sensitive in the same way functions are.

Comment: OR is not going to work, see help which button is it perhaps |

Comment: @RopeyMaps, in [xxxx] or in (xxxx) didn't work either. See the screen shot added with the error message I've got. This shouldn't be that difficult!

Comment: No, it shouldn't! You could scrap the python and use the where clause as optional third argument. That's sql so capital IN. I only have arc at work so can't check till I'm there.

Comment: Question: so the box inside RasterCalculator where SetNull, Con, and all the operations are typed, that should be in Python syntax or in SQL syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [boolean OR operator "|"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-spatial-analyst/boolean-or-operator.htm) .

```
SetNull("rocksoilver12"==10 | "rocksoilver12"==14, "rocksoilver12")
```

Or the [`InList`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/inlist.htm) function:

```
SetNull(InList("rocksoilver12", [10, 14]), "rocksoilver12")
```

Comment: @Delonix  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SetNull(("rocksoilver12"==10) | ("rocksoilver12"==14), "rocksoilver12")
```

I had a similar problem, putting those extra brackets helped me.